# How to redirect user on RESTful web service call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, rest

I've got a Ruby on Rails booking web application which has a REST interface to provide some JSON raw data to multiple PHP based clients websites. Those operations are currently perfectly working.

I now want to allow end users to book on my booking system from the client websites using a RESTful web service. I am looking for a solution like Paypal one:

1. User clicks on the "Book" button on an authorized client website
2. User is redirected to a booking interface on my app, inputs his personal data and confirm his reservation
3. Transaction is saved
4. User is redirected back to the client web site

My question is: How to redirect user to complete his request and how redirect him back after the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.referrer` on the landing page to get the URL from which the user came, and probably store it in the session. Once the booking is complete, you can send the user to the same URL.

Comment: This is a way for the final redirect, yes. But for the first one?